# PHP/MySQL - how to add MySQL data to url in address bar without a form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, url, fetch

I have a website at `localhost:8888/documents/index.php`.

In this file, I load a **random** row from my MySQL table. I have around 1000 rows, and it will randomly pick one row, and return some data from that row into my page. For example, if it chooses row 467 with:

```
name = George
age = 23
key = fe4v6
```

It will show on my `index.php` something like: `hello, George (23 years old)`. The key is a random, unique variable for each row.

**What I want**: I want my URL in the address bar to update **automatically on refresh** with the key attribute. So I want: `localhost:8888/documents/index.php`**`?key=fe4v6`**. When I refresh the page, I want it to update the URL with the new key value for the corresponding row in my MySQL database.

I don't work with forms. I make a connection with my database and I use queries and `fetch_assoc()` on the random row. In my `index.php` I show the name like this:

```
<?php echo $row['name'] ?>
```

I don't know how easy or difficult this is, maybe there is a much easier solution. I would like to hear from you, thanks!

Comment: "refresh" just reloads the CURRENT url. if you awnt to change the url the user sees in the address bar, you have to REDIRECT, e.g. `header('Location: http://example.com/foo.php?id=' . $newid)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use a header redirect

```
if(!isset($_GET['UniqueKey'] {
    header('location: localhost:8888/documents/index.php?UniqueKey='.$row['name']);
}
```

The code firsts checks if UniqueKey is set, so it doesn't redirect infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work (yet). Where I do put this code? I tried the header, I tried in my php file right after the database connection, I tried it after the row data has been concluded. I am still on `localhost:8888/documents/index.php`. I also tried changing it manually to `localhost:8888/documents/index.php?key=` but it doesn't add anything to the url; it stays the same. Also, when I use `exit;` my website is completely blank. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Header redirects needs to be before any output, so good practice is to put it at the top of your code. I've edited my answer, could you please check if it's working now? It works perfectly when i test it locally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Doesn't work. I don't know what is missing. I don't use anything with $_SESSION (not sure what it does). do I need that maybe?

I tried calling it in the <head> of my index.php, completely at the top. In the body; right after the database connection; before any connection. I assume I must call it AFTER the $row variable has been fetched? ugh so much drama..

Comment: A session ($_SESSION) stores values which persists across multiple pages. I think it's a bit overkill to use a session for this application. I'm having trouble seeing why this isn't working for you. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not sure.. I'm pretty much a beginner so I don't know a lot about anything. Bare with me ;)

I have this as a start:

`<html>
 <head>
  <?php
   header('Location: localhost:8888/documents/index.php?UniqueKey='.$row['UniqueKey']);
  ?>`

is that a problem? I understand I must call the header function before any output, but right there is the very start of every bit of code/html. Correct? Furthermore, I'm refreshing the page at `localhost:8888/documents/index.php`, so **without** the `?UniqueKey=` added at the end. Correct?

Comment: The PHP code needs to be before your HTML. Try adding it at the very top of the file, before <html>

Comment: Thanks Esben!! It did something! Right now I have this:
http://<?php include ('custom_search.php'); ?><?php header('Location: http://localhost:8888/documents/index.php?UniqueKey='.$row['UniqueKey']);?><!DOCTYPE html>

but when I do that, it **does** change my URL with the updated key, but my website is blank (doesn't load anything)

Comment: Sounds like a parse error. Please check your error log and post the latest error.

Comment: It gives an error when I inspect the page. It says (roughly translated from Dutch to English): localhost:8888/documents/index.php?UniqueKey=ETAtUo' can not be opened because occurred too many redirects. This problem can occur if you open a page that contains a referral to another page that refers back to the original page.

Comment: This happens because your code keeps redirecting to itself. You should make a check of some sort before executing the redirect, otherwise it will continue to redirect. I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Esben. It's still not working, but I got my URL refreshing like 10 times (10 different keys) without the page loading. I'm gonna accept your answer anyways, feel free to help if you want to.

I am loading this at the very top of my index.php (above the doctype html): `<?php include ('custom_search.php'); ?>`

The solution you provided with !isset is not working, but I'm too much of a noob to even know what it all does. Right now it DOES refresh my URL, but only around 10 times, and not loading a page (no errors; just blank). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you maybe add the contents of custom_search.php to your question so i can inspect it?

Comment: I changed my original question, changed the code somewhat (deleted quite some lines). Hope this will suffice! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `header` as follows. Add this snippet after you have the row value to be passed in as the query string parameter.

```
<?php header('Location: localhost:8888/documents/index.php?key='.$row['key']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work (yet). Where I do put this code? I tried the header, I tried in my php file right after the database connection, I tried it after the row data has been concluded. I am still on localhost:8888/documents/index.php. I also tried changing it manually to localhost:8888/documents/index.php?key= but it doesn't add anything to the url; it stays the same. Also, when I use exit; my website is completely blank. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the History API if you only need to support fairly [recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history).

```
<script>
    var path = "<?php echo "localhost:8888/documents/index.php?key=".$row['key']; ?>";
    var page_title = "Custom Title";
    history.pushState({}, page_title, path);
    document.title = page_title;
</script>
```

This will update the path to add the key as soon as this code is run in the browser (i.e. during the page load). No reload is required so there's no need to program any logic to prevent a new random row being assigned.